# Manage power/ and reset button

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

Is there a way to control what the physical power/reset buttons do?

I'd like the power button to "hibernate", instead of "shut down" to save my session.

Comment: Unless your BIOS offers something, you're not going to be able to control the Reset button's functionality.  I've only ever seen server BIOSs offer it, and in those cases it was just a choice whether to enable it or not.

Comment: You've asked a few questions like this now, and both have been (or will be)closed as duplicates... You find it it easier to do your own research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Click Choose what the power buttons do from left pane`

Choose the appropriate option from drop down, based on your power plan.

Comment: It seems I can't control what reset does.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc - Your are not suppose to.